# VBA to remove CalulatedField from Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write some code to add and then remove a  calculated field to and from a Pivot Table. Below are the two pieces of code:

```
Sub AddPivotField()

    With Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .AddDataField Worksheets(1).PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("hProdUtil"), "Sum of hProdUtil"
        .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#0.0%"
    End With

End Sub
```

And:

```
Sub RemovePivotField()

    With Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1).DataFields("Sum of hProdUtil")
        .Parent.PivotItems(.Name).Visible = False
    End With

End Sub
```

The AddPivotField works fine but when I run the RemovePivotField I get the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1) = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1")?

Comment: I just tried to change it to Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1") and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
Sub RemovePivotField()
    With Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1).DataFields("Sum of hProdUtil")
        .Orientation = xlHidden
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So I've tried that which doesn't work either. I guess that works for values but not calculated fields as you'll see in post #8. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/517597-remove-datafield-pivot-table-using-vba.html

Answer (score 1):

Was able to figure it out by modifying the code on https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)